# How to create a alertdialog using hyperlinks textview in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a Text view in hyperlink,when i click the link i want to open the alert dialog.
How to do this.i knew Separately to create the Alert dialog ,but using hyperlink am getting struggle.

My code

```
policy.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href>PasswordPolicy</a> "));
```

Comment: Set an onclick listener on your textview? Then popup an alert dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves a little trick, **Use underline tag** in strings.xml like below

```
 <string name="tvideo"><u>Video</u></string>
```

Now set this in your TextView in the .xml

and setonclicklistener to that TextView and open your dialog.

Also note that output will be seen during run-time. I'm afraid it will not be visible in Graphical Layout.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to create custom dialog and its text property as linkify.

```
TextView myWebSite = new TextView(this);
myWebSite .setText("http://http://www.google.com/");
Linkify.addLinks(myWebSite , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```